# Install EFI Shell On UEFI Boot

Tags: laptop, uefi, reinstall

I deleted the default installed EFI SHELL 2.7 and I want it back on my UEFI Master Boot. Can anyone tell me how to install it back?

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's EFI shell's version. At least it doesn't say so.

The shell can be downloaded from the [TianoCore repository](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/UDK2018/ShellBinPkg/UefiShell/X64/Shell.efi). You have to place it in the root of EFI System Partition and name the file `shellx64.efi`. The name is case-insensitive because of FAT filesystem.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: How have you deleted it in the first place if you don't know how to access EFI System Partition?

Comment: A UEFI shell does not necessarily have to be located at the ESP root.; only if you want it to be automatically invoked if all other EFI boot paths fail.  Furthermore, the Tianocore EFI shell binary may or may not work. Depends on your firmware version.

Comment: @gronostaj thank you for your answer, I used Window$ partition tool and I format the Drive. How do I install it back?

Comment: Sorry @Alex but I have no idea what you're trying to do. I didn't suggest formatting the drive at any point. If you have another question, please use the _Ask Question_ button at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Create a partition and format it to FAT32. Create an "efi" folder in the new partition and go into the folder you created. Create a "boot" folder in the efi folder. Move the UEFI shell into the boot folder and rename the .efi file to bootx64.efi. reboot. The UEFI boot entry will be added automatically. (NOTE: If you want the shell in the EFI partition you need to boot into the UEFI shell. Make a new directory in the efi folder and copy the "BOOTX64.EFI" to the new folder in the efi partition. Reboot into the BIOS and add an Entry to the shell you copied.)